# AutoCompleteTextView onSubmit event

Tags: android, kotlin, autocompletetextview

I am using a AutoCompleteTextView and my question is if there is a event which gets called when you hit enter on your soft-keyboard?

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was that the AutoCompleteTextView had an attribute `maxLines="1"`, if you pressed enter on the soft keyboard, the event doesn't get called.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to handle submit key you can add a property to `TextInput` component:

```
       onSubmitEditing={this.onSubmitEditing}
```